# Can someone translate this?

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context

Two weeks ago I accidentally installed a virus that installed a program called "UCBrowser". I want to uninstall it but it's written in Chinese. Can someone please translate this for me? If it isn't Chinese please tell me.

[image: UCBrowser Screenshot]

P.S.
I'm sorry if this doesn't fit on this forum or if it's "wrong" for another reason but I don't know any other place where I can get help for this and I can't copy it to Google Translate. I really need to get rid of this. I've already worked for 2 weeks and I'm not done yet. And it is possible that I'm gonna post some other questions like this if i don't know what i have to do in the uninstall process.

[I'm gonna delete this post as soon as I can when my problem is solved because I know this can't help other people, so please don't flag this post.]

Comment: To uninstall a program, you don't need to know what this window is saying.  Just use a third party uninstall app to remove it. If you don't already have an uninstall app, google and find one.

Comment: I got a third party uninstall app but it doesn't show up in that list

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check the box at the lower left corner and click '卸载', which means uninstall at low right corner.

Comment: I don't suggest this because it may be a trap.
If you click that bottom, your data may be gone forever.
It's a common sense.
When you got a virus, do not do what it suggests.
You should use an antivirus program to scan your system and then remove it.

Comment: The virus that i had installed this program along with 3 others, those 3 are gone by using the uninstaller and in case of bad stuff i got a backup of my important data.

Comment: I would say I don't think it's a strict 'virus' (won't hurt your system & CPU), just kinds of. There is an automatic program somewhere forcing you to install it. Actually, this browser is a common browser, and what you will delete after check the box is the browsing data and saved account when you used this browser. So, you can just directly uninstall it. Take easy.